# Custom curent location Annotation pin not updating with core location

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, core-location, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Trying to add a custom pin for current location, However the location does not update. Even after setting `setShowsUserLocation = YES;`

```
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Current Location"]) {
        self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cursor_%i.png", [[Session instance].current_option cursorValue]+1]];
    }
```

However, if I set to `return nil;` everything works fine, but I lose the custom image. I really want to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen the setShowsUserLocation flag only shows the current location using the default blue bubble.

What you need to do here listen for location updates from the phone and manually reposition your annotation yourself. You can do this by creating a CLLocationManager instance and remove and replace your annotation whenever the Location Manager notifies its delegate of an update:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
  // update annotation position here
}
```

To reposition the coordinates, I have a class, Placemark, that conforms to the protocol MKAnnotation:

```
//--- .h ---

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Placemark : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strSubtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *strTitle;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) coordinate;
- (NSString *)subtitle;
- (NSString *)title;

@end

//--- .m ---

@implementation Placemark

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize strSubtitle;
@synthesize strTitle;

- (NSString *)subtitle{
    return self.strSubtitle;
}
- (NSString *)title{
    return self.strTitle;
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c {
    self.coordinate = c;
    [super init];
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then in my mapview controller I place the annotation with:

```
- (void) setPlacemarkWithTitle:(NSString *) title andSubtitle:(NSString *) subtitle forLocation: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) location {

    //remove pins already there...
    NSArray *pins = [mapView annotations];

    for (int i = 0; i<[pins count]; i++) {
      [mapView removeAnnotation:[pins objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    Placemark *placemark=[[Placemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
    placemark.strTitle = title;
    placemark.strSubtitle = subtitle;
    [mapView addAnnotation:placemark];  
    [self setSpan]; //a custom method that ensures the map is centered on the annotation 
}
```

Comment: I tried redrawing the annotations but it's reposition the points. Not too sure how you would set the new location on an annotation?

Comment: I've lifted the code I used from an earlier app and updated it in the answer above. It was written a while back (iOS 3.0!) but it should still be golden. Hope that helps!

Comment: yup helped alot, i had to replace MKUserLocation with a custom MKAnnotation completely. I had that in place for my other points just hadn't thought about replacing it as a whole.