# mapView:didAddAnnotationViews: doesn't respond

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, mkmapview

I am currently reading the iPhone Programming The Big Nerd Ranch Guide and encounter some problem on page 96.

I have assigned the MKMapViewDelegate properly (Tested with several delegates) and each of them respond to the change made. But during this delegate:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];

    id<MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 250, 250);
    [mv setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    NSLog(@"Test");
}
```

The console should log that when the annotation is added. But somehow it doesn't run the method above.

This is the main file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    //[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation:TRUE];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I wonder which part is wrong. Does the [mapView setShowUserLocation:TRUE] add annotation to the map? If it is yes, how come the there is no response from the method above?

Comment: Have you tried placing a pin on the map?

Comment: There is a blue indicator generated from [mapView setShowUserLocation:TRUE], is that considered as pin?

Comment: I'm not sure - just trying adding another pin! :)

Comment: TBH, I have problem trying to add pin. Can you show me how to do it? Because I encounter something like id <MKAnnotation> and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Can you not just touch and hold on the map view on the device?

Comment: No... doesn't show anything for me to add pin.

Comment: You've added your mapView to your window, right? `[self.window addSubview:mapView];` Then you should be able to add a pin just like you can in the Apple "Maps" application.

Comment: I added the mapView using Interface Builder, so it should exist. I can see the map and location of Blue Dot is at Cupertino since it can't detect my location. But, even if I touch and hold.

Comment: So you can never drop a red pin onto the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you haven't added an annotation yet! The blue indicator that show's the user's location isn't classed as an annotation. You can add an annotation by simply dropping a red pin onto the map view (touch and hold the map).

If you want to create your own annotations for the map view programatically, I suggest you start by checking out the section "Annotating the Map" in the [MKMapView class reference documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKMapView) and looking at the [MKAnnotation protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKAnnotation) (if you're unfamiliar with protocols I strongly you suggest you read up on those too!) You can use an instance of the class [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which conforms to this protocol, and you can add an annotation using the `addAnnotation:` instance method of the *MKMapView* class.

Comment: I'm still reading the documentation, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: [mapView addAnnotation:] require an variable id <MKAnnotation>)annotation. I don't know exactly how to create this variable.

Comment: You need to create an instance of a class that conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol and pass this instance to `addAnnotation:`.

Comment: Try adding an instance of MKPinAnnotationView to the map using `addAnnotation:` (it conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes, it actually works after I add pin. But the explanation in the book doesn't add any pin and treat the blue indicator as pin. I have paste the quote from the book. Is it incomplete something is lacking? Expected result is the app zoom to the current location instead of pin.

Comment: Yea maybe the book's wrong, unclear, or maybe the MapKit framework has been changed since it was written.

Comment: Yes, the framework has changed. Now it only call the method when pin is added. But I learned an important lessons from it. Learn how to read documentation. :D, the book is very good. I begin to understand how the MVC model works.

Comment: Yea it's really great. MVC is amazing - funny you mention it, I wrote an article here on it the other day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231175/how-to-let-each-class-interact-with-each-other/5231842#5231842

Comment: Do you notice that I am the same person you answer the question for? :], I sent you an email hoping to get in touch with you on iChat just in case I need to bug you on some help.

Comment: Haha I didn't notice! If you need help your best bets to ask on here. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Custom curent location Annotation pin not updating with core location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176219/custom-curent-location-annotation-pin-not-updating-with-core-location/5176341#5176341) I answered something similar there before

Comment: Thanks, I will use it as reference.